# How to prevent setting of [NSApp dockTile] badgeLabel value that is set not by my code?

Tags: macos, cocoa, apple-push-notifications, badge

I have a push notifications with badge, sounds and alerts enabled. 
If the program is not running - everything is fine. But when the program **is** running - I need to block all sounds, alerts and badges that are not generated by program, because I have a live connection to my server and receiving all events before APNS sends notifications to my mac device.
I've found the way to hide alerts, but I couldn't find any way to take over control on dockTile's icon badge.
if i do this:

```
-(void)application:(NSApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo
{
  [[NSApp dockTile] setBadgeLabel:nil];
}
```

nothing is happened, the badge that is set by APNS still persists. I tried to KVO on badgeLabel or dockTileNumber property as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/416619/how-to-create-a-binding-for-nsapp-docktiles/418747#418747), but observeValueForKeyPath:ofObject:change:context: is never called. How do APNS sets the badgeLabel? Maybe I am doing something wrong and there is a correct way to disable alerts/sounds/badges when the program is running?

Comment: right now I've found some workaround, but this looks very dirty, there have to be a better way

`-(void)application:(NSApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo 
{ 
[application dockTile].badgeLabel = @" "; 
[application dockTile].badgeLabel = @""; 
}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since i did not found any solutions to do it correctly, i will accept my workaround:

```
-(void)application:(NSApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo 
{ 
    [application dockTile].badgeLabel = @" "; 
    [application dockTile].badgeLabel = @""; 
}
```

Alerts may be disabled via `NSUserNotificationCenterDelegate` delegate method `userNotificationCenter:shouldPresentNotification:`:

```
-(BOOL)userNotificationCenter:(NSUserNotificationCenter *)center shouldPresentNotification:(NSUserNotification *)notification
{
    //apple push notification alert will contain userInfo with aps payload, so disable here
    if (notification.userInfo[@"aps"])
        return NO;

    return YES;
}
```

I haven't found any ways to disable sounds.